# Can I use Google Pay for Passes without having a Merchant account?

Tags: google-api, google-pay

Currently, I'm willing to use Google Pay for Passes in order to let users add an event ticket to their google pay app. However, reading the documentation, apparently, I also need a Merchant account on Google. I would like to know if there is any other way to test without having a Merchan yet.

My goal so far is to be able to create just an event ticket class.

I have tried so far using my service account and issuer id, but I'm always receiving and 400 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the codelab: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/passes-loyaltyapi

The codelab will take you through the process of creating a temporary issuer account for development purposes.

Comment: Oh, nice to know about these codelabs. Thanks.